# How to obtain rights to use php command line for a plesk system user

Tags: linux, plesk, plesk-onyx

I´m a real begginer in linux/server/plesk. I had to rent a virtual server Ubunthu to make a test environment.

The company (host) installed automaticaly the Plesk software to help me.
I would like to use a user except `root` via ssh to run some command lines with keys `php` or `composer`.

That works with the user `root` but when I connect by my plesk  system user via ssh, any command was found :

> bash: npm: command not found
>
> bash: php: command not found

etc...

This user is a system user according to Plesk.

Inside the plesk panel, it´s writing this :

> Here you can specify an operating system user for managing files and
>   folders within the webspace by FTP or with File Manager. The system
>   user is also used to access Plesk over SSH (on Linux) or RDP (on
>   Windows) if the corresponding permissions are granted.

If I can access Plesk over SSH, that means I can run command line or just use FTP and File Manager ?

How can I get like a `root` user all command lines for a plesk user ?

My goal is to get a user which can only run command lines inside the plesk scope ( `httpdocs` folder ) and do some actions in the plesk panel, specially in the file manager.

I followed [this tutorial](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909545) for `php` but the `php` command was not included for my system user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Plesk only "System user" specified in **Web Hosting Access** can login to the server via SSH, but this user can not login to Plesk and use File manager.

You need to go to **Plesk > Domains > example.com > Web Hosting Access** and set **Access to the server over SSH** to **/bin/bash**

After that you will be able to login to the server via SSH and execute php commands:

`# ssh your_sysuser@ip
-bash-4.2$ pwd
/var/www/vhosts/example.com
-bash-4.2$ php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr 12 2018 19:02:01)
-bash-4.2$ /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -v
PHP 7.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul 20 2018 12:45:27) ( NTS )`

Login to Plesk is only possible for Client, Reseller or an additional created user.
You need to create an additional user:
**Plesk > Subscriptions > example.com > User > Create User Account**
For more information about Users check [documentation](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/customer-guide/customer-account-administration/managing-additional-user-accounts.69329/)

Comment: I already gave the Access to the server over SSH to `/bin/bash (chrooted)` and I managed to log in via ssh but my problem is `php -v` is not found

Comment: Do I need to restart the server after I did this : https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909545 ?

Comment: I restarted the server without success.

Comment: I understood. I have to use `/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -v` instead of `php -v` which does not work for me.

Comment: You need to set /bin/bash , not /bin/bash (chrooted). In chroot it will not work.
If you want to use chroot then it's needed to apply https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909545 for PHP and all other binaries that you want to use

Comment: Ok, actually, I was doing that : add php, composer.phar as it is written in support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909545